# Python linecache is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, linecache

In Python, I have an issue where whenever I use the `getline()` function from `linecache` module, it won't work at all. Say this was what I had on a text document named `hi.txt`:

```
Hi
```

And say this is what I had on a python program in the same folder/directory:

```
import linecache

print (linecache.getline("hi.txt", 0))
```

It would print nothing, just some blank lines of nothing.

Comment: `linecache.getline` never raises an error: in that case it returns an empty string. Are you sure that you run the program correctly? Can you verify by using `os` that the file exists, etc.

Comment: Yep, I printed the dictionary using os.listdr() and it's there.

Comment: Linecache is not really meant for reading user files, it is a helper for caching *source code* for tracebacks. The fact that it never errors and that it always caches contents makes it unusable for general case. Please stay away from it :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`linecache.getline` starts at 1.

```
print (linecache.getline("hi.txt", 1))
```

does what you expect

```
>>> help(linecache.getline)
> getline(filename, lineno, module_globals=None)
```

by convention `lineno` starts at 1 in any text editor.

Comment: It is a bit lame that it starts from `1` since other lists start from 0 in python.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could have probably went with `use_zero_indexing` kwarg or something :)